# How do you access/iterate through the child elements of a group in SVG.js

Tags: javascript, web, svg, frontend, svg.js

I'm using the SVG.js library, I have a group created with the `draw.group()` function and I'd like to apply attributes to every element in the group. I've tried accessing the `group.children` and `group.childNodes` directly, tried using a `group.forEach(function(){});` loop. Can't figure it out and couldn't find anything in the docs.

On that note, I find the docs somewhat lacking and certainly in no danger of verbosity...

Comment: The docs have a search functionality. Typing children in the search bar would have given you multiple possibilities to solve your problem including `children(), each(), get()`

Comment: I guess I was typing "group" and wondering why it only contains info about creating groups and literally nothing else. A Google search didn't turn up anything so I decided to make a post for the next person with the same problem ‍♂️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the `group.children()` method in the docs which will return an iterable array of the group's children.

Attributes may be applied to each child element using a loop, for example:

```js
for (const child of myGroup.children()) {
  child.attr({
    fill: "#000000"
  });
}
```